# Why doesnt this grab the selected option?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

```
    <div class='divver'>
        Quantity:&nbsp;
        <select class='box' name='qty' id='quantity'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
        <option value='4'>4</option>
            </select>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = document.getElementById("quantity");
    var quant = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
    function checkIt(){
    alert (quant);
    }
</script>
```

On success of the submission I am running checkIt.

```
function submitQuickview()
    {
        if(productForm.validate()){

            //submit the form with ajax
            new Ajax.Request($('product_addtocart_form').action, {
                parameters: $('product_addtocart_form').serialize(true),
                onSuccess: checkIt
            });
        }

        return false;
    }
```

What is wrong?  It always alerts 1 as the quant var no matter the value of the option that is submitted. Any ideas why?  Please note that I am not using jQuery and working in Vanilla or the Prototype framework.

Comment: what does "i am not using jquery" mean?

Comment: it means the majority of the time i try to find a solution using javascript someone will give me a jquery approach which is not an option for me here

Comment: i was teasing ;) most people come on here asking for a jquery answer to everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are assigning a value to the quant variable when the page is being loaded.

In order to get the current value
1) You need to read the selected value within the **checkin** function
   Change your code to as follows:

```
var s = document.getElementById("quantity");     
function checkIt(){     
 var quant = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;     
 alert (quant); 
}
```

**Or**

2) Change the value when the onchange event for the select is triggered.
   Something like:

```
var s = document.getElementById("quantity");     
var quant = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;     
s.onchange = function(){
    quant = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;     
}

function checkIt(){     
 alert (quant); 
}
```

Comment: ahh.. i am a bonehead. Ready for the weekend!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This method avoids creating circular references (or closures that make circular references), and avoids global variables.

```
function submitQuickview() {

   var s = document.getElementById("quantity");

        if(productForm.validate()){

            //submit the form with ajax
            new Ajax.Request($('product_addtocart_form').action, {
                parameters: $('product_addtocart_form').serialize(true),
                onSuccess: checkIt
            });
        }

        return false;
    }

function checkIt() {
   var s = document.getElementById("quantity");
   // grab your value
   var quant = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
   alert(quant);
}
```